# How do I export excel using VBA to an existing ppt slide deck?

Tags: excel, vba, templates, export, powerpoint

I have been trying to create a slide deck from an excel workbook for a couple of weeks now. So far, I have the sheets exporting to a new ppt on the press of a button using VBA (code below). I am wondering how I can export my excel workbook to an *existing* PowerPoint slide deck/presentation. I want to use the same format every single time, and the layout of both the workbook and the slide deck will not change, only the information populated in the slides. Any help is appreciated!

I have tried "Apply.Template" to no avail and get a run time error for invalid request because PowerPoint cannot open the file.

```
Sub Excel_to_PPT_Automation()

Dim PPT_App As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPT_File As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim My_Slide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPT_File = PPT_App.Presentations.Add

Dim Sh As Worksheet

For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sh.Name <> "Start" And Sh.Name <> "Data" And Sh.Name <> "Output" Then
        Set My_Slide = PPT_File.Slides.AddSlide(1, PPT_File.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(6))
    
        'Format Slide Order
    
        My_Slide.MoveTo (PPT_File.Slides.Count)
                        
        'Copy Data and Chart
    
        Sh.UsedRange.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
        My_Slide.Shapes.Paste
    
        With My_Slide.Shapes(2)
            .LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue
            .Width = PPT_File.PageSetup.SlideWidth - 75
        
            .Top = 0
        
            If .Height > PPT_File.PageSetup.SlideHeight Then
               .Height = PPT_File.PageSetup.SlideHeight - 120
            End If
        
            .Left = 0
        
            If .Width > PPT_File.PageSetup.SlideWidth Then
                .Width = PPT_File.PageSetup.SlideWidth - 75
            End If
        
            .Left = (PPT_File.PageSetup.SlideWidth - .Width) / 2
            .Top = 100
                                    
        End With
       
    End If
Next


'First Apply Template attempt resulting in runtime error'

'PPT_File.ApplyTemplate "CE_Template.potx"' 

'Second Apply Template attempt with full path used. Runtime error no longer is present but template is not being applied. Redacting some personal information about my company credentials and company name with "X"s'

 PPT_File.ApplyTemplate "C:\Users\X\OneDrive - X\Documents\Templates\PowerPoint Templates\Cause Evaluation Template.potx" 

End Sub
```

Comment: Try supplying the full path to CE_Template.potx

Comment: `If you refer to an uninstalled presentation design template in a string, a run-time error is generated.`

_From Microsoft documentation:_

> [Presentation.ApplyTemplate method (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.applytemplate?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - this got rid of the runtime error, but it did not apply the template, which is weird. Now the VBA will create the PPT on a blank template but and will finish without error.

Comment: Please edit your original post; comment out the current lines you want to change, add a note about why you're changing them then add the updated code. We can't help you if we don't know exactly what code YOU'RE looking at

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - done.

Comment: @taller - I have been trying to research how to do this, but I cannot find how to add designs through the installer with Microsoft 365 Apps.

Comment: For the sake of maintenance, I'd change "With My_Slide.Shapes(2)" to "With My_Slide.Shapes(My_Slide.Shapes.Count)". That way it's always going to give you the most recently pasted shape, even if something else on the slide changes and Shape#2 is no longer what you think it is.  The .ApplyTemplate line should work as expected, but try it with a file that's not synched with OneDrive. That can cause problems sometimes.